# How to select columns with specific values using unix

Tags: unix, text-files

I have the following sample tab delimited file:

```
.CvR    Col_1    Col_2    Col_3    Col_4    Col_5
S1    1    0    1    0    1
S2    1    1    1    0    1
S3    1    1    1    1    1
S4    1    0    1    1    1
S5    1    0    1    1    1
```

I am trying to come up with a simple way to print the first column and all columns with just "1" values in them.

My desired output file should look like this:

```
.CvR   Col_1    Col_3    Col_5
S1    1    1    1
S2    1    1    1
S3    1    1    1
S4    1    1    1
S5    1    1    1
```

My actual input file will be much bigger. I would like to do this in UNIX where possible. Can anybody help? Thanks.

Comment: what did you try?  awk might help.

Comment: Hi ergonaut, I've been trying awk commands but I can't seem to get it right. I had planned on getting the sum of each column and then write something to say "if the last value in a column = 5, print column" but I just can't quite get it.

Comment: awk '{ sum=+$1-} END {print sum}' infile > OUT; however it errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is reading the file as csv file in Excel, calculate the sum of each column and manually delete the columns you do not want.

Using sed becomes a dirty and slow solution. 
The idea of the sed solution is changing any 0 or 1 value (@Lee: Yes, my comment on your post is valid for me as well, awk seems a better solution) into a fields with the column number and value.
You can count how often the value 1 is found and delete the column when it doesn''t match the total number of rows.
The variable value contains an expression that will be matched with 0 or 1 and will be stored in memory for the \1 construction.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
value='\([01]\)'
cp file file2
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6; do
        sed -i "s/ ${value}/ val${i}_\1/"  file2
done
rowcount=$(wc -l <file2)
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6; do
        if [ $(grep -c val${i}_1 file2) -eq ${rowcount} ]; then
                sed -i "s/val${i}_./1/"  file2
        else
                sed -i "s/Col_${i}//"  file2
                sed -i "s/val${i}_.//"  file2
        fi
done
cat file2
```

Answer (score 2):

u already know how many lines of input file, so just simply get the sum of each col and compare to the last line index minus 1 (sum of col).

```
#!/bin/bash
# colSum is the last line index minus 1
cat input.txt | awk -v colSum=5 '{
    NR != 1
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) {
        sumOfCol[i] += $i
    } 
}
END {
    for (i in sumOfCol) {
        if (sumOfCol[i] == colSum)
            print i
    }
}'
```

after exec this, can get index of col u need. maybe this is a easy way.

Comment: Nice shot, when the values are only 0 or 1. When you want to skip a column with a 2 and a 0, you should test the value of $i before adding it to sumOfCol[i].

Comment: @Walter yeah. right.. i just think this is a simple way when the values are only 0 or 1.  if we can find a easy way to transpose the col to row, then using sed or grep to delete rows have 0.  maybe it's more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
awk '{ print $1 " " $2 " " $4 " " $6 " "  }' file

.CvR Col_1 Col_3 Col_5 
S1 1 1 1 
S2 1 1 1 
S3 1 1 1 
S4 1 1 1 
S5 1 1 1
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but not quite, while that works on this small dataset the actual input file has several thousand columns, I was hoping to find a way to print the columns with just "1" values in it. Would you happen to know a way?

Comment: @Gloom, you'll have to take the time to construct a small sample set of data that does handle all cases you anticipate in your data. As it is know, readers will get to play 20 questions with you to get it right. Please edit your question with revised data set , your best attempt at code AND the error messages you get. Good luck.